# how to make sure I dont get exception error or any kind of error in React that stop execution or crashes the app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When developing React app should we check every property if exists to make sure our app does not crash? I currently have for ex something like below:

```
<h3>{block && block.box && block.box.title}</h3>
```

but I wonder if I should do it like this:

```
<h3>{block && block.box && block.box.title && block.box.title}</h3>
```

to make sure **block.box.title** exists before accessing it!

Any idea how can i handle these things in javascript in general, this approach seems kinda verbose to me.

**UPDATE, should this check be enough:**

```
<h3>{block.box.title && block.box.title}</h3>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example, I think it's safe to assume that `block` exists, otherwise your code is probally incorrectly written, so that check isn't needed.

Then, the double title makes no sense. The syntax you're using (and most people) is a bit of a cheat, it effectivly does this:

```
isset(block) && isset(block.box) &&  echo(block.box.title)===true
```

This makes use of the fact that a string is considered true and that javascript parses from left to right.

```
It evaluates/runs the 1st part: run the ISSET, continue the checks if that's true  
It evaluates/runs the 2nd part: run the ISSET, continue the checks if that's true
...  
It evaluates/runs the last part: Echo the output, continue the checks if it's true.
```

At the last point, it has already output the string, then it evaluates the outcome. If the string hasn't been output (it's empty or it doesnt exists) that will return false.

---

Response to your update: No that wont work. It will try to access the `title` property of null if `box` doesn't exist, which results in an error,

Comment: this is very well explained therefor it deserves ANSWERED! thank you

Answer (score 1):

New js feature here:

```
  <h3>{block?.box?.title}</h3>
```

Comment: While this is a very neat feature, this doesn't answer the question asked :)

Comment: Yes it does. This will do all the checking you need to do and will make sure your app does not crash! <h3>{block.box.title && block.box.title}</h3> this would not be enought you should check one by one every objevt property just like block && block.box && block.box.title

Comment: thank you for your answer, I should consider this new js feature from now on!

Comment: The question asks wether it's useful to first check the existance of `block.box.title` before you echo it (also see the update part). While I like this new feature you suggest, it doesn't explain why his current idea doesnt work :)